# Angular2 upgrade- How to manage?

Tags: angular

Hi i am using angular 2 from last few months.

As we all know it change or new feature comes after few days.

Some time changes are few and some time breaking changes.

Let say=>
As in angular.rc.1 
it has **Routs** decorator, then in angular.rc.4 it has been changes to **RouterConfig** and so many...

I just want to ask that=> do we have any better solution to overcome on such changes to modify code instantly?

as you can think in router changes we almost need to walk through each file where we have router configurations....

So just thinking if anybody have good option to overcome on it.

Comment: What is the reason for the performance tag?

Comment: i just want say that it improve upgrade method and efficient way to such questions...i don't know other tag which point to question if you have then plz suggest..

Answer (score 0):

I've battled with this issue since the early betas. I've come to terms with the fact that using betas, alphas and release candidates will cost you some extra time and effort. It's a hell of a lot easier to use an old and stabile system that stopped updating, patching, improving, etc.

That said - using early versions of software will reward you a lot as well - if you like being nerdy and playing with new shiny stuff. If you like something - enough to use it in any early version - then you're probably eager to upgrade once a new version is released.

Angular2 in the rc versions are supposed to be pretty close to a release version and so far, the only real problem is the router being deprecated and a new comming up.

Unless you're going to rely heavily on specific router features, you probably don't have to upgrade yet. You can wait before upgrading, why upgrade to rc4 when you know it's not the final version? Only reason to upgrade now is if you are directly affected by something fixed in the newer release or if you can't stop upgrading because you enjoy it so much! :)

Myself - I can't help checking daily if something new came out. Then i read the release notes and the bugfixes, changes, etc. I've got some hobby projects I play around with in the evenings/nights after work and my current projects gets an upgrade as soon as i find the time :) I usually just upgrade, then run through the solution (running automatic and manual tests) and try to break it. Then fix the stuff that was broken by the update. That process is usually pretty quick - unless i've skipped several versions, then it can take a little longer...

Comment: I agree with you @per... but i don't think we can blame angular team for it because they are doing good this is my opinion. Still i am looking for something which will say don't worry i will help you!!! KIND

Comment: @PankajBadukale There is no blame :) Just remember what it means to work with alphas, betas and release candidates. Updating and replacing the router shouldn't be that hard - check out an rc4 example and you should be able to figure out what syntax changed in the new router